# Getting "Already present: Duplicate request" errors in YugabyteDB YSQL

Tags: yugabytedb

[Question posted by a user on [YugabyteDB Community Slack](https://www.yugabyte.com/slack)]

Sending a lot of concurrent requests in the YSQL layer, we're getting `Already present: Duplicate request, XX000` errors. Are these safe to retry ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here’s a in-progress list of the retryable cases:

- If you get `Duplicate Request` in the middle of transaction, then it could be safely retried.
- If `Duplicate Request` was generated by standalone statement, then it
  is possible that original statement was executed and applied to db.
  So safety depends on the query and application.
- `Catalog Version Mismatch` — this is really a txn conflict but specifically with a DDL. There’s already an issue to change the error code for this: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/issues/8597.
- Any error with `Try Again`  prefix — but these might already be re-mapped/retried internally.
- `Leader not ready to serve requests.` and `Leader does not have a valid lease.` are also retryable.
- `TimedOut` requests are also retryable in some cases (e.g. for pure reads and operations in transction blocks), but not safe for single-row writes.

Generally for non-XX000 error codes the same rules apply as for vanilla Postgres. (e.g. `40001` is retryable — and we should already map `YB transaction errors` and `read restart required` errors to that error code).

For `XX000` (internal error), there are a number of specific errors that should be safe to retry.

Internally we already re-map some of the errors to YSQL/PG error codes (like mentioned above) and generally we aim to do that appropriately.

The full list of internal error codes are at: https://github.com/yugabyte/yugabyte-db/blob/master/src/yb/util/status.h#L149